# Create a dropdown list from one table and entering selected value into another table (same MySQL DB)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to show a dropdown list of all countries ("land") stored in a look-up table in mySQL database, let the user choose his country, and then entering that coundtry into a memberlist table.

The code below actually updates the member table with a new record, but that the value entered into the land column is the string "$landselect" (not the corresponding/selected country-name).

I suspect that there is something wrong in the way I try to pass on a selected value (i.e. country name) between the SELECT-statement in the HTML-part and the INSERT-statement in the PHP-part, but I cannot get my head around how to pass the correct value (selected country name) to the INSERT-statement.

Any ideas and comments much appreciated.

---

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<form action="Medlem 140112b.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
Password: <input type="text" name="password"><br />
Personnummer: <input type="text" name="personnummer"><br />
First name: <input type="text" name="firstname"><br />
Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname"><br />
Postadress1: <input type="text" name="postadress1"><br />
Postadress2: <input type="text" name="postadress2"><br />
Postnummer: <input type="text" name="postnummer"><br />
Ort: <input type="text" name="ort"><br />
<!---Land: <input type="text" name="land"><br />--->
Land: <SELECT name="land"> <OPTION VALUE=0>Choose
  <?php 
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db ("cf", $con);
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT Land FROM land",$con);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $landselect=$row["Land"];
  echo '<OPTION VALUE=\'$landselect\'>'.$landselect.'</OPTION>';
  }
  mysql_close ($con); //stänger connectio till DB system;
 ?>
</SELECT>   
<br />
Epost: <input type="text" name="epost"><br />
Telefon: <input type="text" name="telefon"><br />
TC_approval: <input type="text" name="tc_approval"><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>  

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db ("cf", $con);
if (mysql_error())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
} else echo "Koppling till DB gick bra!";
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO medlem(Username, Password, Personnummer, Firstname, Lastname,    Postadress1, Postadress2, Postnummer, Ort, Land, Epost, Telefon, TC_approval)  VALUES('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]','$_POST[personnummer]','$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[postadress1]','$_POST[postadress2]','$_POST[postnummer]  ','$_POST[ort]','$_POST[land]','$_POST[epost]','$_POST[telefon]','1')"; 
echo $sql;
mysql_query($sql, $con); //Exekverar tabellskapandet; 
}
mysql_close ($con); //stänger connectio till DB system;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sql injection attack here we come - pleases dont insert raw user input in to your db ever.

Comment: and TIP, use die() or throw exception instead of simple echo in if statement (mysql_error()) die() because you don't miss any important error. Echo doesn't always show errors correctly

Comment: VALUES('$_POST[username]' is not a valid array name, try change this $_POST['username']

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
echo '<OPTION VALUE=\'$landselect\'>'.$landselect.'</OPTION>';
```

to

```
echo '<OPTION VALUE=\'' . $landselect . '\'>'.$landselect.'</OPTION>';
```

your current code would work if using double quotes, but single quotes are not magic quotes.

Comment: better use '<OPTION VALUE="' . $landselect . '">'.$landselect.'</OPTION>';

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo '<OPTION VALUE=\'$landselect\'>'.$landselect.'</OPTION>';
```

try this

```
echo "<OPTION VALUE='$landselect'>$landselect</OPTION>";
```

And also try to use  `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Your current code is prone to sql injection.